# Shield UI Legend Interactivity

Tags: javascript, shieldui

I would like to know whether there is any interactivity in the chart legend of the Shield UI Charts? For instance can data series be hidden by using the legend? Are there any special properties to be set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The chart legend items can be used to hide/show data series on the chart. However it is worth noticing, that if a series is not added to the legend it obviously cannot be hidden/shown from its list of items.

The legend's interactivity is also enhanced by the ability to additionally format its active/inactive elements:

```
legendItemSettings: {
    disabledStyle: {
        color: 'red'           
    }
}
```